# componentWillUpdate() not working as desired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-class-based-component

I have a class component, called **ListOfItems.js**, that lists a bunch of objects like so (btw, I am required to use *class* components, not *function* components):

```
class ListOfItems extends Component {
  construction (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      objectList: []
    }
  }
}

// This gets the list of objects to display
componentDidMount() {
   this.getObjectList();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  //not sure what to put for "previous ObjectList"
  if( this.state.ObjectList !== previous ObjectList) {
     this.getObjectList();
  }
}
```

Inside of **Object.js** (the file for each object displayed in ListOfItems), I have a **delete functionality**, where if the user selected the "x" icon on the object, that object is deleted from the list. An instance of the Object.js inside of ListOfItems.js looks like this:

```
// BTW, I cannot change anything here. I have simplified
// my code very heavily for this purposes of this question.
{this.state.objectList.map(item) => {
  <Object 
    objectList={this.objectList}
    data={item}
    //few other props here
  >
}
```

I can see that the object is removed right after I click on "x", as per the api fetch response that I console logged. And when I refresh the page manually, the object is removed from the list displayed.

**GOAL:** **I want the removal to happen in real time, right after the user clicks "x".**

Comment: what is `this.state.marObjectList `? is it a typo and you meant `this.state.objectList`?

Comment: What props do you have in `Object`? Does it provide some `onDelete` callback?

Comment: @Georgy Yes, fixed.

Comment: easiest way to check for an array `length`: `if( this.state.objectList.length !== previous.objectList.length) {
     this.getObjectList();
  }`. Also you could use `onDelete` callback as @BANOnotIT mentioned and do not use `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: @BANOnotIT I have edited the question to include the props. I have not provided a callback in `onDelete`. I am not sure how this work. I need to have another function inside of `onDelete` that would rerender the parent `ListOfItems.js` page, correct? How would I do this?

Comment: @Georgy, thanks for your response. I am not sure how to get the previous `objectList`. Is `previous.objectList.length` an actual usable statement? Is the `this.state.objectList.length` immediately decremented upon deleting the object, even if it is not reflected on the UI?

Comment: I resolved this issue. The only problem is that componentWillUpdate keeps getting called infinitely, even though I have a conditional inside of it and the state changes only once. I have updated my code above.